# OnChange for whole page: Blazor

Tags: c#, html, onchange, blazor

I want an alert if a user want to leave the page and doesnt save the changes in blazor.

How can i detect the change with high performance (dont want to check the database)?

In blazor the @bind values updating automatically. I guess there is a service that checked already something changed.

How can i get this information?

Comment: Most of the time the pages just show you an alert if closing a page that MAY have unsaved data, no actual checking whatsoever. just a event listener on `window.onclose` with a `confirm()`

Comment: true, but some people open the page 100 times a day. and i dont want to ask them everytime :D

Comment: maybe you can set a flag `modified` on the model and update it on changes, then resetting it on save, and check for its value onclose

Comment: i load the model once OnInitializedAsync(), and the next call is, if the user wants to save. So i think it won't workt with my structure 
but i think go with serialize the object at start and if the user want to change page.
thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `IsModified()` from the `EditContext`:

```
@if (_editContext.IsModified())
{
    <p>You have made changes. Any unsaved changes will be lost!</p>
}

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSumit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText @bind-Value="Model.Something" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</EditForm>


@code {
    public Model Model { get; set; } = new Model();

    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(Model);
    }
}
```

For checking if the user wants to navigate to another page, here is a great article: https://chrissainty.com/an-in-depth-look-at-routing-in-blazor/
and: https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/